# Use javascript to find the current url from address bar in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I change the bookmark in the url when the page is loaded. That way, when the user clicks the back button of the browser, the browser will not actually go back, but will instead change the bookmark. I can then detect the bookmark change and do something else as a reaction to the user pressing the back button.

My problem is to find the current url, including any bookmark/hash changes. It works in all browsers, using a combination of the following, but not in IE8:

```
document.URL
location.href
window.location.hash
```

and the `window.onhashchange`

As it doesn't work for IE8, could anyone possibly point me in the right direction towards how I can detect the bookmark/hash change in IE8?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288209(VS.85).aspx claims that `onhashchange` works in IE8… it doesn't?

Comment: @ephemient It's not working for me in IE 8.0.7600: http://jsbin.com/obofe4/3/edit

Comment: Turns out my IE8 is in quirks mode, which doesn't support the event.  I love how Microsoft, in the article @ephemient cited, pretends like it works across the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [jquery-bbq](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/), as it implements the hashchange and makes it work in IE6-IE8 and possibly IE9 now. You could probably entirely rely on it instead of your custom code.

Comment: Hi meder - thanks a lot. I will try it out, but however strange it sounds, jquery is not easily implementable in my project. Therefore I'm still interested in knowing the core javascript function that can be used, which must be what jquery is also using.

Answer (score 1):

According to the author of the [jQuery hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/), IE8 supports binding to the `window.onhashchange` event out of the box.

Perhaps you could try using Ben's plugin, which is intended to enable hash change detection on older browsers.

**EDIT:** [My tests](http://jsbin.com/obofe4/3/edit) showed that the event is not firing in IE8.  Then I found the following comment in above plugin's source code:

```
// Note that IE8 running in
// IE7 compatibility mode reports true for 'onhashchange' in window, even
// though the event isn't supported, so also test document.documentMode.
```

Apparently, I'm running in [documentMode 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196988%28VS.85%29.aspx) which is quirks mode.  I bet it works in IE8 standards mode only.  Regardless, you should be able to implement the same [JS code](http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq/raw/v1.2.1/jquery.ba-bbq.js) that Ben used.